# Configuring a project to launch with .NET Core 3.1

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

I am trying to use Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition to build and run a program that depends on .NET Core 3.1.

I have installed the correct version using `dotnet-install` which placed it into `AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet`.

When I run the program from Visual Studio, I get an error suggesting that it cannot find the installed .NET Core. ("To run this program, you must install .NET Core.")

Even if I run `dotnet build` followed by `dotnet run --project MyProject` -- which I assume sets correct `PATH`, etc. --- the same error happens.

How can I configure Visual Studio so that it can find the .NET Core installation?

Answer (score 0):

For developing .NET Applications you require the SDK. 
For running applications you need the .NET Runtime.

The SDK has the runtime bundled with it.
At the time of posting, these can be downloaded from Microsoft's website
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet

As the website states though, .NET Core 3.1 is end of life. You should look to migrate to .NET 6 or .NET 7

Comment: There is no .NET Core 3.1 installer for my architecture (arm64). You can download the binaries for ARM but this is effectively the same thing as using `dotnet-install`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work from the command line by creating a `global.json` file in the top level of my repo containing:

```json
{ "sdk": { "version": "3.1.422" } }
```

then when I ran `dotnet --version` it confirmed that it was going to use .NET Core 3.1.422.

Subsequently I could use `dotnet run --project MyProject --framework netcoreapp3.1`.

I did not figure out how to do it from Visual Studio, which would be better because I could then more easily enter the debugger. So I will leave this marked unanswered.